# boto3 list ONLY directories on bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've got a dataset on an s3 bucket that is on the format:

```
s3://bucket-name/<hash_0>/image.jpg
s3://bucket-name/<hash_0>/data.json
s3://bucket-name/<hash_1>/image.jpg
s3://bucket-name/<hash_1>/data.json
```

In which each <hash_i> represents a "data point" containing an image and a json file.

I'm trying to iterate through the bucket but I need to iterate only through the directories, since the name of the json and image files are known beforehand.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket="dataset")
for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        logging.info(f"{obj=}")
```

All I wanted was a bucket.ls command or a max_depth parameter on the paginate function. How could I do this using boto3 library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket="dataset", Delimiter='/', Prefix='')
for page in pages:
    for obj in page['CommonPrefixes']:
        print(obj['Prefix'])
```